# R concatenate several cells into one without getting NA

Tags: r, merge, na

I have already been browsing through some of the anwsers on stackflow, but I don't understand much (yet) of the many sophisticated solutions, I just started on R two weeks ago. This is a sample data.frame:

```
#rm(list = ls()) 
A= c(1,2,3)
B= c("Africa", "Asia", NA)
C= c("Tiger", "Bear", "Dog")

df =  data.frame(A, B, C, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


  A      B     C             
1 1 Africa Tiger    
2 2   Asia  Bear    
3 3   <NA>   Dog
```

I would like to merge my columns so that it looks like this:

```
A= c(1,2,3)
B= c("Africa", "Asia", NA)
C= c("Tiger", "Bear", "Dog")
D= c("1AfricaTiger", "2AsiaBear", "3Dog")
Howitshouldlook = data.frame(A, B, C, D, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



  A      B     C            D
  1 Africa Tiger 1AfricaTiger
  2   Asia  Bear    2AsiaBear
  3   <NA>   Dog         3Dog
```

What I tried was:

```
df$D <- with(df, paste(df$A, df$B, df$C))
```

The result was unfortunately

```
  A      B     C              D
  1 Africa Tiger 1 Africa Tiger
  2   Asia  Bear    2 Asia Bear
  3   <NA>   Dog       3 NA Dog
```

I already read that the NA is often a problem, but I dont seem to find an easy solution to this. Can someone either link me to a beginners' solution or either explain to me how I can merge cells without the "NA" as well as without the blanks?

Many thanks! 
Steffi

Comment: To paste without spaces, use `paste0()` instead, or add `sep=""` to the paste arguments.

Comment: df$D=gsub("NA","",paste0(as.character(df$A),df$B,df$C))

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code

```
test<- function(str){
  ifelse(is.na(str), "", str)
}

df$D <- with(df, paste0(test(df$A), test(df$B), test(df$C)))
```

It gives this output

```
> df
  A      B     C            D
1 1 Africa Tiger 1AfricaTiger
2 2   Asia  Bear    2AsiaBear
3 3   <NA>   Dog         3Dog
```

Comment: use `paste0` instead of `paste` and you'll get rid of the blanks as well

Answer (score 2):

The `replace` function can be used on a whole data.frame:

```
do.call(paste0, replace(df, is.na(df), ""))
#[1] "1AfricaTiger" "2AsiaBear"    "3Dog"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> data.frame(df, D=apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x),collapse="") ))
  A      B     C        D
1 1 Africa Tiger 1AfricaTiger
2 2   Asia  Bear    2AsiaBear
3 3   <NA>   Dog         3Dog
```